# Amazon Athena external lambda function (udf) - create view

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, user-defined-functions, amazon-athena, federated

I am trying to create an external function in Athena using AWS Lambda function. I am able to do so and query successfully using Athena query editor. Code is below.

```
using external function s3signedurl(col1 VARCHAR) returns varchar lambda 'customudf'
select incident, pdfloc, s3signedurl(pdfloc) as s3_signed_url
from "lambdapoc"."lambdametadata"
```

**However I want to create a View on top of this so I can query it easily like a table/view** (Select * from MYVIEW) from a Reporting Tool like Tableau OR any other tool which connects to Athena.
I don't seem to find the documentation for it or any examples on the Internet.

**Please note**: Column 's3_signed_url' data is dynamically generated from Lambda function and it will change everytime the query is executed.

[image]

**Can anyone help?**

Answer (score 0):

I just got to know that "**Using connectors or UDFs in Views are not supported**". It is mentioned in their [GitHub Repo](https://github.com/awslabs/aws-athena-query-federation/wiki/Limitations_And_Issues).
Closing this question

Answer (score 0):

Might be worth exploring if a [Create Table As Select (CTAS)](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/athena/latest/ug/ctas.html) table would meet your needs. I believe it is compatible with UDFs